# SAS logistics regression prediction

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sas

I am making a model to discern people who would most possibly buy
stock then offer a list for the bank to make a better sales calling.
I have selected some features and create some features based on
time-series to train logistics regression(which its code has already
finished by others)

And now I have the outcomes ,and figures are on:http://blog.csdn.net/jinghuibeng1032/article/details/78026823 (cause my office colud not connect to net and could just take
photos of it.some of the columns are in Chinese and I have marked index and  translate it in English),anyone know what the graphics mean? any suggestions to improve it?

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen hi,could you pls offer a little help for this question？thanks !